# segmentation fault while erasing set

Tags: segmentation-fault, set, iteration, erase

first, the following code produce a segmentatin fault and I dont know why.

```
    float currX;
    float currY;

    int id = 0;

    for(;it != s.end();){
        it_copy = it;
        pair<float,float> p = *it;
        currX = p.first;
        currY = p.second;

        currTresh = thresh;
        while(currTresh > 0 && it_copy != s.end()){
            pair<float,float> inner_p = *it_copy;
            currTresh--;
            if((inner_p.first-currX)<=secondThresh &&
                    abs(currY-inner_p.second)<=secondThresh){
                group.push_back(pair<int,KeyPoint>(id,KeyPoint(Point2f(p.first,p.second),9,-1,0,0,0)));
                s.erase(it_copy++);
            } else {
                ++it_copy;
            }
        }
        id++;
        it++;
    }
```

Here is the scenario:
I try to group some Points.
Points which are similar e.g. similar coordinates. For example
P1(10,5) ; P2(11,6) ; p3(11,50) 
Group1(P1,P2) ; Group2(P3)

I will realize this as follows.

The use of set brings the advantage that duplicates are removed and the pairs of x and y coordinates are sorted.

The for-loop should iterate over the complete set s. Here the iterator 'it' is used.
In a inner while-loop I will pick a amount of values of s, depend of the tresh.
thresh and sencondThresh are 10!
In the while-loop I set the condition that similar points are grouped. If a point insert in the group I will earase it from the set s. To avoid, that the same Point is in different groups.
And this is the line, I think the segmentation fault comes from.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `erase` modifies `s`, invalidating `it`. So you can't increment `it` after that.

Perhaps you intended `it = it_copy;` rather than `it++;`?

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. How i can fix it? Because i need to increment it.

Comment: See my last sentence. You never use `it_copy`, and it seems like it's set up for precisely this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, but this don't give the result I need. For each value in the set s i try to iterate over the next 10 values, erase if the condition is true but after that i will jump back to the very first element in the set s which I haven't visit.

Comment: Then you need to adjust your code so that `it_copy` always winds up pointing to that next element and put `it=it_copy;` at the end of your loop.